# Comment keybindings not working properly in MyEclipse, possibly due to CodeMix

Tags: typescript, comments, myeclipse

Up until a few days ago my My Eclipse 2017 keybindings for toggling comments in `typescript` and `JavaScript` was `control-slash` and `control-shift-slash` and `control-shift-backslash` for block comments in `html`.

However, now the only binding I've found that works is `control-alt-slash` which only adds `html`-style comments in both `typescript` and `JavaScript` and `html`. The keybinding does not toggle comments out and `control-alt-backslash` does nothing.

I did two things that may have caused this:

I installed CodeMix on MyEclipse. However, I uninstalled all CodeMix extensions and the problem still occurs.

I changed the name of my MyEclipse workspace, which caused MyEclipse to create a new empty workspace with the old name. I tried pointing MyEclipse to the newly renamed workspace but that caused filepath errors so I just changed the name back and deleted the empty workspace. I'm worried some of the workspace preferences got changed during this process and is causing my problem.

I've tried changing the keybindings but nothing seems to work. I've included some screenshots of the keybinding screens and the results of using control-alt-slash in typescript.

According to this [thread](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/block-comments-not-working/) Genuitec is aware of the problem and is working on fixing it, but I can't find any updates on the problem since the last post in the thread at the end of February 2018.

Any help would be great! I might try reinstalling MyEclipse but I'd really rather not...

Thanks

I don't have sufficient reputation on Stack Overflow to link all the pictures so there's a couple in my first comment.

[image: edit key bindings screen]

Comment: [active key bindings](https://i.imgur.com/WjoIUBG.png) ,
[code with wrong comment type](https://i.imgur.com/fmQPO8z.png)

Comment: I ended up reinstalling MyEclipse and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Sorry you had to do that. We are working on the problem and have this rather inadequate workaround, in the meantime: use CTRL-SHIFT-P and start typing Add Line Comment or Toggle Line/Block Comment.  It remembers recent commands you've used so should be quick to run again.

Comment: Uninstall worked for me. The first thing out of the box was it was telling me to escape the '<' character. Not exactly angular friendly. Then the uninstall would not work, and the box they gave me to disable did not either. Looks to me like somebody wants to put Angular IDE out of business, or they are just a complete incomp.